# Ruby on Rails cart

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi i'm new to ruby on rails and im trying to create a cart for my events application, i've done most of the work but I cant quite figure out this part

```
  def add_item
    @event = Event.find(params[:cart][:event_id])
    @ticket_types = @event.ticket_types.where(id: params[:cart][:ticket_type_id])

    params[:cart][:ticket_type_id].each_with_index do |ticket_type_id, index|
      ticket_type = @event.ticket_types.find(ticket_type_id)
      if params[:quantity] === 0
      else
        current_cart.line_items.create(
          ticket_type_id: ticket_type.id,
          quantity: params[:cart][:quantity][index]
        )
      end
    end

    redirect_to cart_url
  end
```

This is my cart controller and the def thats used to add line items. 
Expected Results: when a user see all the various ticket types with their value preset to "0", they can choose the quantity of any of them and submit it to the carts page.

Actual Results: All ticket types values are submitted to the carts page including the ticket types with the value on "0".

Their will be no cost applied to a ticket type with the value of 0 but I do not need to see them

```
<% @ticket_types.each do |ticket_type| %>
                     <div class="pb-2">
                       <h5>
                         <%= ticket_type.name %> <%= number_to_currency(ticket_type.cost_ec) %> per ticket
                       </h5>
                       <div class="px-5 ">
                         <div class="input-group mb-3">
                           <%= form.hidden_field :ticket_type_id, value: ticket_type.id, multiple: true %>
                           <%= select_tag('cart[quantity][]', options_for_select(0..ticket_type.limit), { class: 'form-control' }) %>
                           <div class="input-group-append">
                             <button  type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#details">Ticket Details</button>
                             <!-- Modal -->
                             <div class="modal fade" id="details" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="details">
                               <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                 <div class="modal-content">
                                   <div class="p-5">
                                     <p>Description <br>
                                     <%= ticket_type.description %></p><br>
                                     <p>Ticket closes at:  <%= ticket_type.end_at.stamp('Friday, 31/12/00 12:59 ') %></p><br>
                                   </div>
                                 </div>
                               </div>
                             </div>
                             <!--end of modal -->
                           </div>
                         </div>
                       </div> 
                     </div>
                   <% end %>
```

Can anyone tell me what my if function in mt controller is doing wrong?

Here are my params hash

```
Started POST "/cart" for ::1 at 2020-06-05 13:45:11 -0400
Processing by CartsController#add_item as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"hl1C56tE6DJIyjJme8wK8Bak5l2icVymCwTe5SA8TCqt3TdtqlCoNzgEj0c2+URpzytG/LF4Xh6fBLfKJhHNTQ==", "cart"=>{"event_id"=>"3", "ticket_type_id"=>["2", "5", "6", "7"], "quantity"=>["5", "4", "3", "0"]}}
  Event Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/carts_controller.rb:21
  TicketType Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "ticket_types".* FROM "ticket_types" WHERE "ticket_types"."event_id" = $1 AND "ticket_types"."id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["event_id", 3], ["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/carts_controller.rb:25
  TicketType Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "ticket_types".* FROM "ticket_types" WHERE "ticket_types"."event_id" = $1 AND "ticket_types"."id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["event_id", 3], ["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/carts_controller.rb:25
  TicketType Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "ticket_types".* FROM "ticket_types" WHERE "ticket_types"."event_id" = $1 AND "ticket_types"."id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["event_id", 3], ["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/carts_controller.rb:25
  TicketType Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "ticket_types".* FROM "ticket_types" WHERE "ticket_types"."event_id" = $1 AND "ticket_types"."id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["event_id", 3], ["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/carts_controller.rb:25
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/cart
Completed 302 Found in 18ms (ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)


Started GET "/cart" for ::1 at 2020-06-05 13:45:11 -0400
Processing by CartsController#show as HTML
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:21
  Cart Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:21
  Rendering carts/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  LineItem Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."cart_id" = $1  [["cart_id", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/carts/show.html.erb:25
  TicketType Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "ticket_types".* FROM "ticket_types" WHERE "ticket_types"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/carts/show.html.erb:27
  Event Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/carts/show.html.erb:27
  Rendered carts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (39.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (4.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_alerts.html.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 297ms (Views: 185.2ms | ActiveRecord: 10.2ms)


Started GET "/cart?reload" for ::1 at 2020-06-05 13:45:12 -0400
Processing by CartsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"reload"=>nil}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:21
  Cart Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:21
  Rendering carts/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  LineItem Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."cart_id" = $1  [["cart_id", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/carts/show.html.erb:25
  TicketType Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "ticket_types".* FROM "ticket_types" WHERE "ticket_types"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/carts/show.html.erb:27
  Event Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/carts/show.html.erb:27
  Rendered carts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (27.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (3.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_alerts.html.erb (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 270ms (Views: 181.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.2ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple problems, so, this is the params hash:

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"hl1C56tE6DJIyjJme8wK8Bak5l2icVymCwTe5SA8TCqt3TdtqlCoNzgEj0c2+URpzytG/LF4Xh6fBLfKJhHNTQ==", "cart"=>{"event_id"=>"3", "ticket_type_id"=>["2", "5", "6", "7"], "quantity"=>["5", "4", "3", "0"]}}
```

You might need to permit those params in the controller, something like:

```
def cart_params
  params.require(:cart).permit(:event_id, :ticket_type_id, :quantity)
end
```

then, your condition:

```
if params[:quantity] === 0
```

is comparing both the value and the type of object for that value, so, it's making this:

```
string === integer
```

but you aren't using the correct keys, it should be:

```
if params[:cart][quantity][index] === 0
```

Since `quantity` is an array

you can fix this by doing:

```
  if cart_params[:cart][quantity][index] === 0
```

Also, you can use `unless` instead and probably you might want to cast the value:

```
  unless cart_params[:cart][:quantity][index].to_i < 1
```

And even better, you can also make this validation on the js part of your form, that way you avoid having going back to the controller to make this validation

Comment: I tried using the first 2 suggestions you made and it is still submitting tickets with the quantity of "0"  as for using it in js im not quite sure how to go about that one. @mr_sudaca

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake in my example, it should be `unless params[:quantity].to_i < 1` instead of `unless params[:quantity].to_i > 0`

Comment: `unless params[:quantity].to_i < 1` dosent submit anything to the cart page

Comment: could you paste the params hash in the question?

Comment: i just added them

Comment: cool, I made some edits to my answers, let me know if that works on your code

Comment: this `if params[:cart][quantity][index] === 0` did not work so i went on to using the unless but the controller gave me an error  ***undefined method [] for nil:NilClass*** so i changed `unless cart_params[:cart][:quantity][index].to_i < 1` to `unless params[:cart][:quantity][index].to_i < 1` and it works, i dont know if this is the way you intended because to avoid injected code rails sets params so nothing bout those would be injected. Regardless im very thankful for your help